# Como posso deixar a minha janela em modo tela cheia utilizando javascript ou jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando deixar a pagina em fullscreen ao abri-lá o código abaixo só deixa maximilizada tem com deixar full screen

```
<script>
    window.moveTo(0,0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: Tem [APIs](http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/11/javascript-jquery-fullscreen-browser-window-html5-technology/) que fazem algo asism mas acho que não dá p/ fazer isso no load da página. Dá p/ criar um botão ou controle que chama chama a função do navegador, isso não é uma função do js então o máximo que vc pode fazer é "pedir" ao navegador